# Rewriting ASP.NET (.aspx) pages in Apache

Tags: asp.net, apache, iis

I managed to get ASP.NET to work in Apache, as per http://weblogs.asp.net/israelio/archive/2005/09/11/424852.aspx

but I'm unsure how to get it to rewrite pages, with a web.config file.

I've tried using Google endlessly, but came to nothing.

What's the best solution for me to rename my pages, e.g.
mytestpage.aspx to mytestpage.htm

Also, anyone know how to get IIS and MySQL working? I've tried but I'm struggling to get it to work.

I did this simply because I needed multiple sites on port 80 on localhost, and the website I'm developing is not suited to PHP. IIS is installed, but not being used at the moment.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use mod_rewrite.

Something like:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/([^\./]+)\.aspx /$1.htm [PT,L]
```